# I can not register in database as a member php with ajax for register activity

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a project and I must use ajax with php. I want to register member to database. The feedback says yes but the database stays empty. It took too much. Here is my form and ajax codes:

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <script>
        function kayit(){
            var bilgiler = $("#kayitformu").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                data : bilgiler,
                url : "kayit.php",
                success: function(kayitol) {
                    if($.trim(kayitol) == "bos") {
                        sweetAlert('Hata','Boş alan bırakmayınız','error');
                    } else if ($.trim(kayitol) == "var") {
                        sweetAlert('Hata','Bu e posta zaten kayıtlı','error');
                    } else if ($.trim(kayitol)=="ok") {
                        sweetAlert('ok','Kayıt Başarılı','success');
                    } else if ($.trim(kayitol)=="hata") {
                        sweetAlert('Hata','Sistem Kaynaklı Hata Var','error');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        </script>
        <form action="" id="kayitformu" onsubmit="return false;" method="POST">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="adsoyad" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="eposta" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" name="sifre" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" onclick="kayit();" name="Gonder" class="btn btn-primary" >
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my sql codes:

```
<?php 

require 'baglan.php';

if($_POST) {
    $ad= $_POST["adsoyad"];
    $eposta = $_POST["eposta"];
    $sifre = $_POST["sifre"];

    $sifrele = sha1(md5($sifre));

    if(!$ad || !$eposta || !$sifre) {
        echo "bos";
    } else {
        $varmi = $db->prepare("SELECT eposta FROM uyeler WHERE eposta =:e");
        $varmi->execute(array(':e'=>$eposta));

        if($varmi->rowCount()) {
            echo "var";
        } else {
            $kayit = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uyeler  SET
                adsoyad=:a,
                eposta =:e,
                sifre =:s
                ");
            $kayit->execute([':a'=>$ad,':e'=>$eposta,':s'=>$sifrele]);

            if ($kayit) {
                echo "ok";
            } else {
                echo "hata";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In ajax code I forward the informations to php file, but I don't now why database doesnt get the records? Can you please explain where is the error?

Comment: In you section "SQL code", `$kayit->execute(...)` you use `$sifrele`.  But in the `if(...)` you check `!$sifre`.  Are you certain `$sifrele` is not empty?  To debug, echo the INSERT query into a log and try to run it manually.

Comment: Almost i tried all ways but it is same :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the wrong syntax for mysql `INSERT`. You are mixing the `UPDATE` statement with the `INSERT` query. Should be:

```
$kayit = $db->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO
            `uyeler`
            (`adsoyad`, `eposta`, `sifre`)
        VALUES
            (:a, :e, :s)");
```

See the examples on the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html

Comment: It is same sir. :( Other example in the internet it is working.

Comment: If you have the correct syntax now, then you may want to check sql logs and see if there are any errors. Perhaps you have a unique column where you shouldn't and it's not letting you insert, or something similar. If you have the correct syntax now, then it should be working.